# Error H10 App Crash on Heroku with Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I'm deploying an app with Django==1.11.15 and Python==2.7.15 on Heroku and 
the push worked fine and return this comment:

```
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v6
remote:        https://healthylifeweb.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

But the aplication link show an error and suggest and command to see the log, i wrote the command but i don't know how to solve the error.

The log file:

```
$ heroku logs --tail

2018-10-11T12:53:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user albertosanmartinmartinez@gmail.com
2018-10-11T12:54:28.286159+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-10-11T12:54:35.285542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn healthylife.healthylife.wsgi`
2018-10-11T12:54:28.042239+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user albertosanmartinmartinez@gmail.com
2018-10-11T12:54:28.042239+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 3fdfd02c by user albertosanmartinmartinez@gmail.com
2018-10-11T12:54:38.258853+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2018-10-11T12:54:38.259422+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:29420 (4)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.259529+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-10-11T12:54:38.263124+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2018-10-11T12:54:38.339002+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871148+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871197+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871199+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871202+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871205+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871204+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871228+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871231+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871234+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871235+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871238+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871239+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871241+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871243+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871245+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871247+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871249+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/healthylife/healthylife/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871250+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871254+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871252+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871255+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871257+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871259+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871260+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871262+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871267+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871263+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871265+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871270+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871269+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871569+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872009+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-10-11T12:54:38.871272+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'healthylife.settings'
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872012+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872020+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872015+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872017+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872034+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872019+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872022+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872032+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872024+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872038+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872036+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872039+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872043+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872030+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872052+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872047+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872041+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872048+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872050+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872045+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/healthylife/healthylife/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872054+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872057+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872056+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872059+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872061+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872063+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872065+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872066+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872072+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872078+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'healthylife.settings'
2018-10-11T12:54:38.872360+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2018-10-11T12:54:38.916603+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-10-11T12:54:38.916696+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 12:54:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2018-10-11T12:54:38.987540+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2018-10-11T12:54:39.005194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-10-11T12:54:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-10-11T12:55:36.337449+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=healthylifeweb.herokuapp.com request_id=7339127c-a858-44b4-b999-3ed2f824b2a0 fwd="2.154.234.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-11T12:55:41.265443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=healthylifeweb.herokuapp.com request_id=f536ae9e-44fe-4e30-9216-05654e039682 fwd="2.154.234.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

GitHub repository link:

https://github.com/AlbertoSanmartinMartinez/HealthyLifeWeb

Anybody could help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ImportError: No module named corsheaders.middleware - Did you update your requirements before deploying ?

Comment: I'm sorry, delete those dependencies and forget that line